# Overriding a "compiled statement" in python

Tags: python, overriding

For the sake of argument, let us say that I wanted to create my own module with a name like math (which is already pre-defined) and then import it from another module.  Here is the directory structure of my code:

```
__init__.py
math.py
```

So in the `__init__.py` I wish to do like

```
from math import whatever
```

If I run `__init__.py`, the built-in math will be chosen instead of the math module I have included, but I want to access my math module.  The only way I have found to get around this is to simply rename math.py to something different like mymath.py.  How can I accomplish this while keeping the original name of the module?

Comment: Why must it have the same name?

Comment: Because I am not the original author of the module.  No one is holding a gun to my head, but I defer to the original author.  Plus, I learn something new this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is a bad idea to name your module with the same name as stdlib modules. You may not know when you will trip over unexpected results.

Secondly, what you are saying is perfectly possible.

1. Create a dir by name `foo`.
2. Create `__init__.py` with the content you mentioned.
3. Create `math.py` with a content such as `print "something"`
4. If you do `python __init__.py` you will that something is printed.

Perhaps you are doing something else?

Comment: I retried and it is as I say for my configuration.  When the name is the same as the default module, I get an ImportError.  When the name is something different, the program executes until completion. I work with PyDev and my default Python version is currently 3.1.

Comment: Ok, I see for me it was a PyDev configuration issue (telling Eclipse what the src directory is correctly).  This answer should in fact work and is a proper explanation (and jogged my mind).  So if I did `from mypackage.math import whatever` that should be good enough.  I acknowledge it is VERY poor practice to duplicate a default module name, but I tried to explain my rationale for THIS particular scenario in the question section.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is frowned upon to replace default modules -- you don't know the side effects. I think I should first recommend that you place it in some subfolder (if it is in the folder "my" you could just `import my.math as math`), after that I suggest renaming it.

If you must, you can then make sure the path to math.py is first in sys.path. You could probably just do:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0,os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 1):

if your package is called testpack you can do:

**testpack/myfile.py**

```
import math
from testpack import math as mymath

print (math.sin(3))
print (mymath.hello())
```

where **testpack/math.py** is:

```
def hello():
    print ('this is math')
```

this gives you:

```
0.14112000806
this is math
```

so you can use both math modules

**Edit**: Updated for python 3.x
**Note**: The folder estructure is:

```
mypackages\
  __ini__.py
  ..........
  ..........
  testpack\
      __init__.py
      math.py
      myfile.py
```